# EvoPdf loading images from Dropbox

Tags: pdf-conversion, evopdf

I have an application that I put some drop box images like (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u3xjkrah9fzm7ju/AAB_TLn83FQH456O79od0_moa/3286Z.png?dl=1)
and then I convert the page to a PDF using EVOPDF, but these images aren't rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I just set to download all resources before the render

Dim converter As New EvoPdf.HtmlToPdfConverter()
converter.DownloadAllResources = True

Comment: Yep I would say this is the usual 'gotta wait for images to download before expecting to see them' issue that you see in HTML5 canvas image missing stylee issues.